# Return subclass of return object in override of abstract method

Tags: java, c#, methods, overriding, abstract

I am porting a portion of [Google Gson](https://github.com/google/gson/tree/master/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson) (Java) to C#. The `public abstract class` [JsonElement](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/JsonElement.java) defines the following:

```
public abstract JsonElement deepCopy();
```

which can be easily translated into C#:

```
public abstract JsonElement DeepCopy();
```

The `public final class` [JsonArray](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/JsonArray.java) (`public sealed class` in C#), which extends JsonElement, defines the following:

```
@Override
public JsonArray deepCopy() {
    //irrelevant code
}
```

which I attempted to translate into C#:

```
public override JsonArray DeepCopy()
{
    //irrelevant code
}
```

However, this produces an error:

> 'JsonArray.DeepCopy()': return type must be 'JsonElement' to match overridden member 'JsonElement.DeepCopy()'

How do I work around this?

Comment: you are looking for ["new" modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-modifier)

Comment: but be aware that this is not _"override"_ - it is _"hiding a member"_

Comment: also be aware that `Java` != `C#` so _"translated"_ - is a wrong word. They differ in so many ways, so there is **a lot** of things that just **can't** be translated. You should **rewrite**, not translate.

Comment: @vasily.sib "**trans·late** *(verb)*: express the sense of (words or text) in another language." No one likes a pedant.

Comment: "**un·​trans·​lat·​able** _(adjective)_: unable to be translated, not translatable" No one likes a snapper